# How do I create a 'Most Recently Popular' bar for content in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a **noob** so please forgive if this is an easy question but I'm trying to create a 'Most Recently Popular' output for specific content on a rails project.

Right now the object I am pulling from has an attribute revision.background_title. I want to calculate popularity by finding the number of specific background_title's added over the past seven days then put them in order. For example if there are 4 background_title's named 'awesomecontent' then that would be above one that has 1 background_title named 'less awesome content'

This pulls all of them:

@revisions = Revision.find(:all, :order => "created_at desc")

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the basic ActiveRecord `find` method to do this.  The code would end up looking something like this:

```
@revisions = Revision.all(
  :select => "background_title, count(*) count",  # Return title and count
  :group => 'background_title',                   # Group by the title
  :order => '2 desc'                              # Order by the count descending
)
```

To see the output, you could then do something like this:

```
@revisions.each do |revision|
  puts "Revision #{revision.background_title} appears #{revision.count} times"
end
```

giving

```
Revision z appears 10 times
Revision a appears 3 times
Revision b appears 2 times
```

Another option would be to take a look at `ActiveRecord::Calculations`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html

Calculations supports a `count` method that also supports the `group` option.  However, going this route will give you back a hash containing the `background_title` as the key and the `count` as the value.  Personally, find the first method more useful.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.

Any suggestions on how to do this with a constraint on the time? For example, most popular in the past 7 days?

Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, just add a `:conditions` option to the hash.  For example: `Revision.all(:select => "text", :group => "text", :conditions => ['created_at > ?', 7.days.ago], :order => "text")`.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing. It's not letting me pull any other attributes associated with revisions - just revision.background_title and revision.count not revision.title. Is there a way to add that attribute into the group?